# IOS SplitView TableViewController query

Tags: ios, ipad, initialization, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I have one SplitViewController with default settings added into an xib file. Its Table View controller i defined as another class (in Identity Inspector) as a TableView Controller class I created.

Now I have put some code in its 
     ...numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger) section
 and ...cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath

It works fine with total values in its table according to numberOfRows I have defined and elements in cell according to what cells I create and return in the appropriate method.

My question is:

1. How is table coming into the SplitView because when I customize UITableView in the xib of my TableViewController, its changes do not appear in the SplitView's left section. (I guess that table View is non-customizable? )
2. Secondly How does iOS initialize that TableViewController class from XIB because I have to put some initialization code that when that TableView is created, do following things. I tried over-riding various init functions it does not call any of those. How can I initialize some data when that TableViewController is initialized?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The table view is customized in the XIB that contains the split view and not in an own XIB file
2. You can do 2 things: override `initWithCoder:` (remember to use the `self=[super initWithCoder:` pattern) or override `- (void)awakeFromNib`